# I dont know how to create a program that prints out my integers or strings in numerical/alphabetical order

Tags: c++

I dont know how to make this book exercise that wants me to print out three integers or three strings in numerical/alphabetical order.

I've tried using if statements to solve this but it just fails because im a beginner.

with code like this if(a

```
cout << a << b << c << endl;
```

expected results is the numbers i typed in but printed out in numerical order.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
using namespace std; 
int main() { 
    cout << "Enter three whole numbers" << endl; int a,b,c; cin >> a >> b >> c; 
    if(a<b<c) { 
        cout << a << "," << b << "," << c << endl; 
    } 
    if(b<a<c) { 
        cout << b << "," << a << "," << c << endl; 
    } 
    if(c<a<b) { 
        cout << c << "," << a << "," << b << endl; 
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Nice you shared that with us, but that's not a suitable question for Stack Overflow, sorry.

Comment: _"The complete code im trying ..."_ Please [edit] your question to show your code. As you can easily see comments aren't appropriate doing so.

Comment: As a general rule when asking on stack overflow "my code doesn't work" doesn't help people understanding the problem. If you get errors from the compiler, add them in the question. If you have an unexpected behaviour, describe it together to the desired behaviour.

Comment: In your case, the error is the `if` evaluation. `(a<b<c)` does not do what you are thinking. http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/201564/

Comment: it's a duplicate too...

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

int main() { 
    std::cout << "Enter three whole numbers" << std::endl; int a,b,c; std::cin >> a >> b >> c;
    if (a > b) std::swap(a, b); // a < b ? c
    if (b > c) std::swap(b, c); // a ? b < c and a < c
    if (a > b) std::swap(a, b); // a < b < c
    std::cout << a << "," << b << "," << c << std::endl;
    return 0; 
}
```